# Cakephp Update a list set priority

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-ui-sortable

I am new into cakephp.

I have a list of task itens and need to update using cakephp, after dragging and dropping, so this will set the priority of the task itens :

order view:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>  
        $(function() {
            $( "#sortable" ).sortable({   
                placeholder: "ui-sortable-placeholder"   
            });  
        });  
    </script> 
 <ul id="sortable">  
    <?php foreach ($tasks as $task): ?>
        <li class="ui-state-default"  value="<?=$task['Task']['id']?>"><?=$task['Task']['title']?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($task); ?> 
</ul>
```

How can i get the position and the id from the list to have it read on the priority method of the task Controller ?

task controller:

```
public function priority(){

        foreach($tasks as $task){
            $this->Task->query("UPDATE tasks SET priority = ? WHERE id = $id");
        }

    }
```

Thank´s in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problem(s) have you encountered?  I don't see any code related to your actual question.

Comment: Until now i just list the itens, i do not know how to get the altered order and update the table column :     'code' <?php echo $this->Form->create('Task', array('action'=>'priority')); ?>  
  <ul id="sortable">
   <?php foreach ($tasks as $task): ?>    
       <li class="ui-state-default" value="<?=$task['Task']['id']?>">
        <?=$task['Task']['title']?> 
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value'=>$task['Task']['id'])); ?>        
       </li>      
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>  
  <?php echo $this->Form->end('Reorder'); ?>'code'

Comment: i just do not know how to pass javascript variables to php using cakephp. I would like to get the number of the order for the itens to update on the sql table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax.  When the order is changed, call your Ajax function that runs `/tasks/priority'.